# Testing the Go model

Tags: json, go

So this is one of my Go models:

```
type ObjectReference struct {
IRI           string    `json:"iri" bson:"iri"`
ObjectType    string    `json:"objectType" bson:"objectType,omitempty"`
ActivityType  string    `json:"activityType,omitempty" bson:"activityType,omitempty"`
Errors                  `bson:"-"`
```

}

I have a validation on the ActivityType as:

```
   objTypeSuccess := o.ObjectType == "activity"
success = success && objTypeSuccess
if (!objTypeSuccess) {
    o.errors = append(o.errors, "Object objectType supplied : " + o.ObjectType + " is invalid. Valid object types are : [activity]")
}
```

where

```
o *ObjectReference is in the func() definition
```

I am trying to write a test as so:

```
        testObj = models.ObjectReference{
        // Invalid Obj Type
        IRI: "http://localhost:8001/launched",
        ObjectType: ????,
        ActivityType: testObjType,
    }
```

I don't quite understand how I could initialize the `ObjectType` in my testObj. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Set it to a string whose value is not `"activity"`?

Comment: I'm just curious why did you copy pasted code you don't understand, because you definitely copy-pasted this code if you are clueless what is that ObjectType. And that validation is on ObjectType, not on ActivityType. It's pretty obvious you will want at least a positive and a negative test for ObjectType. So perhaps you want a version where you put the value "activity" and one which is not "activity."

Answer (score 1):

The `ObjectReference.ObjectType` is a field of type `string`. That being said you can initialize it with an expression of type `string`. The most basic/simple expression of type `string` is a string literal such as `"hello"`.

Since in your test code you compare it to the value `"activity"`, I assume that is what you want to initialize it with. You can do that like this:

```
testObj = models.ObjectReference{
    IRI: "http://localhost:8001/launched",
    ObjectType: "activity",
    ActivityType: testObjType,
}
```

But of course you can specify any other values/expressions of type `stirng`:

```
testObj = models.ObjectReference{
    IRI: "http://localhost:8001/launched",
    ObjectType: "NOT-AN-ACTIVITY",
    ActivityType: testObjType,
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Go and this helped me rectify the error. Thanks.